# How to specify sort order on multiple self joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I've an attribute table like

```
CREATE TABLE attributes (
    attribute_id INT,
    product_id INT,
    random INT,
    UNIQUE KEY (attribute_id,random,product_id),
    KEY (product_id)
);
```

`random` is a random integer number calculated on insert for shuffling products (that's O.K. for my needs). There are self-join queries like

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.product_id
FROM attibutes x
INNER JOIN attributes y ON x.product_id=y.product_id
INNER JOIN attributes z ON x.product_id=z.product_id
WHERE x.attribute_id IN (20000085,20000090) AND
    y.attribute_id IN (10000007) AND
    z.attribute_id IN (30000050,30000040,30000012)
LIMIT 0,100;
```

As you can see I want to select products which have at least one attribue in each number range. MySQL is so clever to choose table alias for first query itself, depending on selectivity of UNIQUE key. As expected the result is sorted in order of column `random` because of UNIQUE key.
But how can I advise MySQL to revert the order? When adding `ORDER BY x.random DESC` it could happen that MySQL uses filesort for ordering because if it uses table alias `y` for base query (because of better selectivity of attribute ID 10000007) it has to use UNIQUE key of alias `x`. The problem is: I don't know which alias MySQL does use (it's decided by its query optimizer). So how to specify order direction?

(I want to note that table contains about 60 million rows, so usage of filesort or not would be significant in response time)

Comment: Perhaps if you use a `left join`, the optimizer will be tricked into always choosing `x`.

Comment: That's not what I want, because if `x.attribute_id  IN (...)` returns 3 million rows, but `y.attribute_id IN (...)` returns only 50k rows, it would be better to choose `y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check if this version is faster:

```
SELECT a.product_id
FROM attibutes a
WHERE a.attribute_id IN (20000085, 20000090, 10000007, 30000050, 30000040, 30000012) 
GROUP BY a.product_id
HAVING SUM(a.attribute_id IN (20000085, 20000090) ) > 0 AND
       SUM(a.attribute_id IN (10000007) ) > 0 AND
       SUM(a.attribute_id IN (30000050, 30000040, 30000012) ) > 0
ORDER BY a.rand
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

The `GROUP BY` should be about the same effort as the `SELECT DISTINCT`.  You will still incur the overhead for sorting by a random number, but sometimes this formulation works from a performance-perspective.

EDIT:

If you put the random number in the products table, the following might do what you want:

```
select p.*
from products p
where exists (select 1 from attributes a where p.product_id = a.product_id and a.attribute_id IN (20000085, 20000090) ) and
      exists (select 1 from attributes a where p.product_id = a.product_id and a.attribute_id IN (10000007) ) and
      exists (select 1 from attributes a where p.product_id = a.product_id and a.attribute_id IN (30000050, 30000040, 30000012) )
order by p.rand
limit 5;
```

Hmmm, if you store the random number in the products table, you could just `join` that into your query and use it in the `order by`.  That might also work.

Comment: That is not faster for me, because in this case MySQL collects all rows for all attribute IDs. For example: if `y.attribute_id IN (...)` returns 50k rows and `x.attribute_id IN (...)` returns 3 million rows, it is better to query `y` first. I've already tried your approach.

Comment: I've tested your second approach (in your EDIT). Initially `explain` looks really good, no `temporary` and no `filesort`. But testing your solution against mine gave the difference. For 60 million rows in attribute table and 8,5 million rows in product table, my statement took 0,02 seconds and yours 0,40 seconds. So still no solution for me. BTW: you forgot `a.product_id=p.id AND` in your `EXISTS` clauses.

Comment: @rabudde . . . If should at least be consistent, though, because it doesn't depend on the order of a driving table.  As written, it might always take almost exactly the same time.  Making `rand` a clustered index might have a bit impact on performance.